# Rectifiable sets and examples

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is the union of the countable collection of rectifiable sets $S_1, S_2, \dots$.

How can we show that $S_1 \bigcup \dots \bigcup S_n$ is rectifiable? Also, is there an example showing that S need not be rectifiable?

My proof:

From the definition of rectifiable, if we look at a bounded set S in R^n, then whose volume over S of the constant function 1 is integrable.

Also, A subset S of R^n is rectifiable iff S is bounded and Bd S has measure Zero.

So, we are told that S is bounded and we need to show that Bd(S) is zero. For S is bounded, and Bd(S) = Reals, which has measure zero.

Comment: Probably you need to add a definition (or reference) for "rectifiable set".

Comment: pls see above..

Answer (score 2):

With the definition, we can see your answer.  You need to prove: $\text{Bd}(A \cup B) \subseteq \text{Bd}A \cup \text{Bd}B$.  Then it follows that a *finite* union of rectifiable sets is rectifiable.

I assume when you write $S_1 \bigcup \dots \bigcup S_n$ you mean a finite union.  Plus I assume it was a mistake that the number $n$ of sets in the union is the same as the dimension of your space $\mathbb R^n$.

On the other hand, your statement has "countable" in there, too.  Did you want that?  A countable union of rectifiable sets need not be rectifiable.  For example, a singleton $\{r\}$ is rectifiable, but a countable set, dense in the unit ball, is not rectifiable, although it is a countable union of those singletons.

Comment: Another way to do this could be using?:
 Let $S_1 , ... , S_k$ be bounded sets in $R^n$; assume
$S_i\cap S_j$ has measure zero whenever $i\neq j$. Let $S = S_1\cup · · · \cup S_k$. If $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable over each set $S_i$ , then f is integrable over $S$ and $\int_{S}f=\int_{S_1}f+\int_{S_2}f+...+\int_{S_k}f$?

Comment: No. Because last equality is false